# Raspberry Pi Zero Embedded

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi, embedded

First I want to point out that I'm very new to Raspberry Pis. I have bought a Raspberry Pi Zero for my project, because Arduino did not have enough horsepower.

My Project involves an I2C sensor and audio output (I2S). The audio is generated on the Raspberry and that is why I need the computational power.

Now I'd like to know what would be a good choice for the operating system. I don't really need anything else but the I2C and I2S and some math to generate the sound. The project is going to have the Raspberry embedded in the system and is battery powered, so it should be able to survive sudden power loss.

I found something relating to Real Time Operating systems, but I'm not sure if I need it to be exactly real time since I can buffer the generated sound data. But I do need the system to be fast, and as light as possible as the sound generation is rather heavy process.

I understand this is sort of vague question and I'm happy with any information I can get and if you could just point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to get downvoted because this question is open ended and primarily opinion based. You should consider rewording it to: "What operating system does X" to make it more specific.

Comment: @amingilani That's what I tried to avoid with the "What would be a good choice..." instead of "what would be the best..." since I don't really care what is the best. I just need one that works.

Comment: AFAIK there is a porting of FreeRTOS for Raspeberry Pi. Surely supports I2C and i2s. I don't know what is your audio generation code.

Comment: You need to think about what you need from an OS.  Just a scheduler?  Mailboxes?  File system?  Network stacks?  You say you need just I2C and I2S, and math, but none of that requires an OS.  Math is a compiler library, and you can easily write your own serial drivers.

Comment: @Ross Yes, I don't think I really need an OS, as I want to use the Raspberry basically as a micro controller. Is then going bare metal the 'best' choice? Do you know any good tutorials for coding the raspberry this way?

Comment: Raspebbery mount an SoC very complicated, going bare metal can be a very huge job. But probably you can find something on the web to start with. Try taking a look at [this stackexchange answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1258)

Comment: actually the linux level SoCs are generally much easier to program than microcontrollers and microcontrollers are pretty easy.  There is a bare metal raspberry pi community and lots of examples.  I bet though that you can just run a stock linux and not worry to much about this, you will already be out running the i2c most likely so why do you need to grossly out run the i2c?  or the i2s for that matter.

Comment: I have decided to use some linux based OS, as I might need files and such later, which is easier with OS. I just strip all unneeded packages and services and code the program in C for speed. Thanks for all the input!